# Ignite issue when a node in the cluster becomes unstable unable to join the cluster and hangs indefinitely

Tags: ignite

HI I am facing a critical issue with Ignite in our production servers . We have 2 instances with heap sizes of 8gb each . Sometimes due to long gc pause or network issue one of our instances gets stopped . This causes aws auto-scaling to kick in and bring another instance up . This is fine but we have observed that in tis state the grid becomes unstable and our new ignite instaces are never able to join the topology and hang forever causing new autoscaled instances to come again and again .The workaround for this is to restart other instances in the cluster as doing so causes nodes to join again .But ideally in a prod environment this should happen automatically with auto scaling .
Had also added a longer failuredetection timeout but that also doesnt solve it completely and we still observe this sometimes .

The logs observed on the new instances not coming up is as below .Igite version use is 2.4 and off heap mode is used for partitioned caches .Our grid is setup using tcp discovery service using a s3 bucket .

> I have some transactional caches as well which do lock based on
>   tryLocks.

```
evtLatch=0, remaining=[a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1272213534]]]
    2018-07-18 16:34:10.534 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], node=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.534 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], node=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.534 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Ready affinity version: AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0]
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.535 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Last exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931660255, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=32, nodeId8=7d5e83aa, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531931329481], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, addrs=[10.83.87.131, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47500], discPort=47500, order=26, intOrder=14, lastExchangeTime=1531931329258, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931660255, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=32, nodeId8=7d5e83aa, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531931329481], nodeId=7d5e83aa, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=true, hash=247159314], init=true, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=PartitionReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[ExplicitLockReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], TxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], AtomicUpdateReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], DataStreamerReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]]]], exchActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=null, stopCaches=null, startGrps=[], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1531931329576, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=SRV, evtLatch=0, remaining=[a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1272213534]]
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.535 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.a.i.i.p.c.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - First 10 pending exchange futures [total=0]
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.535 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Last 10 exchange futures (total: 1):
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931660255, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], done=false]
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Pending transactions:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Pending explicit locks:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Pending cache futures:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Pending atomic cache futures:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Pending data streamer futures:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.536 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Pending transaction deadlock detection futures:
    2018-07-18 16:34:20.547 UTC [FDPS] [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#28%fdps%] [INFO ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Exchange future waiting for coordinator response [crd=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0]]
    Remote node information:
    General node info [id=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, client=false, discoTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], time=12:34:20.537]
    Partitions exchange info [readyVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0]]
    Last initialized exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ba6aba6c-7f5d-41bf-bfcc-5eefcad36b62, addrs=[10.83.85.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-85-122.ec2.internal/10.83.85.122:47500], discPort=47500, order=30, intOrder=16, lastExchangeTime=1531930705943, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=30, nodeId8=a450db0b, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ba6aba6c-7f5d-41bf-bfcc-5eefcad36b62, addrs=[10.83.85.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-85-122.ec2.internal/10.83.85.122:47500], discPort=47500, order=30, intOrder=16, lastExchangeTime=1531930705943, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531930706210], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, addrs=[10.83.87.131, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47500], discPort=47500, order=26, intOrder=14, lastExchangeTime=1531931660254, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ba6aba6c-7f5d-41bf-bfcc-5eefcad36b62, addrs=[10.83.85.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-85-122.ec2.internal/10.83.85.122:47500], discPort=47500, order=30, intOrder=16, lastExchangeTime=1531930705943, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=30, nodeId8=a450db0b, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ba6aba6c-7f5d-41bf-bfcc-5eefcad36b62, addrs=[10.83.85.122, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-85-122.ec2.internal/10.83.85.122:47500], discPort=47500, order=30, intOrder=16, lastExchangeTime=1531930705943, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531930706210], nodeId=ba6aba6c, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1921954756], init=false, lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1531930704443, nodeOrder=0], partReleaseFut=PartitionReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], futures=[ExplicitLockReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], futures=[ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935479, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39726, id=559000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=221, val=49583853497448469294730566354366524577617095530402283666, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547787212113, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39741, id=603904, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=288, val=49583853499611641578988037213538229804531966271996035234, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935487, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39740, id=558993, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=133, val=49583853497448469294730566354417299462040910024459419794, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935323, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39728, id=558949, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=1023, val=49583853497448469294730566353278491339963927967496667282, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935470, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39951, id=559009, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=556, val=49583853497448469294730566354226289182541798339977937042, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935497, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39683, id=558982, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=373, val=49583853497448469294730566354541818821461216966893109394, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935339, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39682, id=558941, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=156, val=49583853497448469294730566353353444740780034976328450194, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935358, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39936, id=558921, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=59, val=49583853497448469294730566353578304943228356208982229138, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandida... and 48550 skipped ...ead=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935486, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39894, id=558992, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=488, val=49583853497448469294730566354434224423515514832905306258, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], ExplicitLockSpan [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], firstCand=GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=141782290, order=1547786935331, nodeOrder=26], threadId=39893, id=558948, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], reentry=null, otherNodeId=null, otherVer=null, mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=null, serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=570, val=49583853497448469294730566353289371672340459630069022866, hasValBytes=false], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=0|reentry=0|used=0|tx=0|single_implicit=0|dht_local=0|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]]]], TxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], AtomicUpdateReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], DataStreamerReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]]]], exchActions=null, affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1531930706210, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=CRD, evtLatch=0, remaining=[ba6aba6c-7f5d-41bf-bfcc-5eefcad36b62], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=325602672]]
    Communication SPI statistics [rmtNode=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6]
    Communication SPI recovery descriptors: 
    [key=ConnectionKey [nodeId=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, idx=0, connCnt=0], msgsSent=5, msgsAckedByRmt=0, msgsRcvd=7, lastAcked=0, reserveCnt=1, descIdHash=1972345954]
    Communication SPI clients: 
    [node=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=5740, bytesSent=77322, bytesRcvd0=853, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3, igniteInstanceName=fdps, finished=false, hashCode=2068348067, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#28%fdps%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=7, sentCnt=5, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931329178, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=262144, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=7, sentCnt=5, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931329178, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=262144, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.83.87.131:47100, rmtAddr=/10.83.89.183:34664, createTime=1531931330498, closeTime=0, bytesSent=77322, bytesRcvd=5740, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=853, sndSchedTime=1531931330498, lastSndTime=1531931500547, lastRcvTime=1531931660527, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@665c2413, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1531931330508, closed=false, connIdx=0]]]
    NIO sessions statistics:
    >> Selector info [idx=3, keysCnt=1, bytesRcvd=5740, bytesRcvd0=853, bytesSent=77322, bytesSent0=0]
    Connection info [in=true, rmtAddr=/10.83.89.183:34664, locAddr=/10.83.87.131:47100, msgsSent=5, msgsAckedByRmt=0, descIdHash=1972345954, unackedMsgs=[IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage], msgsRcvd=7, lastAcked=0, descIdHash=1972345954, bytesRcvd=5740, bytesRcvd0=853, bytesSent=77322, bytesSent0=0, opQueueSize=0]
    Exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931329178, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=32, nodeId8=a450db0b, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931329178, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531931329402], crd=null, exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931329178, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=32, nodeId8=a450db0b, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931329178, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531931329402], nodeId=7d5e83aa, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=980776600], init=false, lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1531931327875, nodeOrder=0], partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=null, affChangeMsg=null, initTs=0, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=null, evtLatch=0, remaining=[], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=2138568466]]
    Local communication statistics:
    Communication SPI statistics [rmtNode=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9]
    Communication SPI recovery descriptors: 
    [key=ConnectionKey [nodeId=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, idx=0, connCnt=-1], msgsSent=7, msgsAckedByRmt=0, msgsRcvd=6, lastAcked=0, reserveCnt=1, descIdHash=1891649612]
    Communication SPI clients: 
    Communication SPI clients: 
    [node=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=92833, bytesSent=5698, bytesRcvd0=15539, bytesSent0=853, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0, igniteInstanceName=fdps, finished=false, hashCode=2040212682, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#25%fdps%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=6, sentCnt=7, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, addrs=[10.83.87.131, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47500], discPort=47500, order=26, intOrder=14, lastExchangeTime=1531931329258, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=262144, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=6, sentCnt=7, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, addrs=[10.83.87.131, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47500], discPort=47500, order=26, intOrder=14, lastExchangeTime=1531931329258, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=262144, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.83.89.183:34664, rmtAddr=ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47100, createTime=1531931330468, closeTime=0, bytesSent=5698, bytesRcvd=92833, bytesSent0=853, bytesRcvd0=15539, sndSchedTime=1531931330468, lastSndTime=1531931660528, lastRcvTime=1531931660538, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@72024a61, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1531931330468, closed=false, connIdx=0]]]
    NIO sessions statistics:
    >> Selector info [idx=0, keysCnt=1, bytesRcvd=92833, bytesRcvd0=15539, bytesSent=5698, bytesSent0=853]
    Connection info [in=false, rmtAddr=ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47100, locAddr=/10.83.89.183:34664, msgsSent=7, msgsAckedByRmt=0, descIdHash=1891649612, unackedMsgs=[GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage], msgsRcvd=6, lastAcked=0, descIdHash=1891649612, bytesRcvd=92833, bytesRcvd0=15539, bytesSent=5698, bytesSent0=853, opQueueSize=0]
    2018-07-18 16:34:29.598 UTC [FDPS] [localhost-startStop-1] [WARN ] [,] o.a.i.i.p.c.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Still waiting for initial partition map exchange [fut=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931669507, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=32, nodeId8=7d5e83aa, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531931329481], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9, addrs=[10.83.87.131, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-87-131.ec2.internal/10.83.87.131:47500], discPort=47500, order=26, intOrder=14, lastExchangeTime=1531931329258, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6, addrs=[10.83.89.183, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, ip-10-83-89-183.ec2.internal/10.83.89.183:47500], discPort=47500, order=32, intOrder=17, lastExchangeTime=1531931669507, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=32, nodeId8=7d5e83aa, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1531931329481], nodeId=7d5e83aa, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=true, hash=247159314], init=true, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=PartitionReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[ExplicitLockReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], TxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], AtomicUpdateReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], DataStreamerReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]]]], exchActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=null, stopCaches=null, startGrps=[], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1531931329576, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=SRV, evtLatch=0, remaining=[a450db0b-ce86-4f0b-a34b-a2f9c83bb3d9], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1272213534]]]
    2018-07-18 16:34:30.537 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], node=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:
    2018-07-18 16:34:40.537 UTC [FDPS] [exchange-worker-#35%fdps%] [WARN ] [,] o.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], node=7d5e83aa-736a-4190-8b64-7261db7382f6]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:
```

**Info about the other node 10-83-85-122**

The other joining node never got started and was stuck in the ignite start phase . The logs also dont show the node to get up or the ip discovery to get kicked in . to eventually cause the node to be removed via autoscaling .

**Transactional errors received**

```
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to acquire lock for keys (primary node left grid, retry transaction if possible) [keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=281,
```

Answer (score 3):

Partition map exchange is a process of exchanging information between nodes where each piece of data is stored. It happens every time, when topology changes.

Every node sends a `GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage` to a coordinator. Once the coordinator collected all such messages, it sends `GridDhtPartitionsFullMessage` back to other nodes. These messages are sent over communication SPI.

But if some of non-coordinator nodes don't send the SingleMessage to the coordinator, or if the coordinator doesn't send the FullMessage, then "Failed to wait for partition map exchange" error occurs.

Judging by the piece of log, that you provided, a node with *ID=ba6aba6c* didn't send the SingleMessage to the coordinator. It may mean, that communication SPI doesn't work there properly. Make sure, that ports, that are required for communication SPI are available. Usually it's 47100..47200.

Also joining node may be stuck on something. Look at its log to figure out, what happens there.

Comment: HI @Denis you are right the other node 10-83-85-122 did not start up and was stuck in the ignite start process which caused it to be removed via aws autoscaling . My question was why was it not able to join the cluster . Also restarting the active node did cause it to rejoin the network . Is there any reason to why it was stuck , couldn't get anything from the logs just that the code after start ignition was stuck .